# Google Play Service's proguard configuration, in my app or in the lib project?

Tags: android, proguard, google-play-services

I need help please regarding proguard in a referenced Google Play Services project.

Setup:
Android project (Andengine) referencing the Google Play services.

Problem:
Previously I used proguard to obfuscate my code, now after adding the Google Play Services, in the documentation they required to add the pro-guard configuration to the project.

The question is, should I add it to the proguard-project.txt under my own app which already has proguard enabled?
Or should I enable proguard inside the Google-play-services-lib project and add the configuration (it is already there)? ( In the later case proguard is by default disabled.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you generate singed apk for production, you use proguard with your own configuration file because you want to obfuscate your code.
Just add google play service's proguard configuration part to your own config and enjoy.